# How can I avoid the overflow?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, hsv, image-thresholding

I need to convert an image to HSV. I used the library OpenCV but when I run my algorithm I have the following warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
```

I want to calculate distance between two HSV piexels. I implemented the function:

```
def distance(pixel1, pixel2):
    h1, s1, v1 = pixel1[0], pixel1[1], pixel1[2]
    h2, s2, v2 = pixel2[0], pixel2[1], pixel2][2]
    dh = abs(h1 - h2) / 179
    ds = abs(s1 - s2) / 255
    dv = abs(v1 - v2) / 255
    distance = math.sqrt(dh ** 2 + ds ** 2 + dv ** 2) / math.sqrt(3)
return distance
```

When I execute the following code the results are not correct because of the overflow. In some cases the distance is grater than 1.0 and that shouldn't happen.

```
  import cv2
  import math
  import numpy as np
  #threshold value in range (0,1]
  threshold = 0.7689
  image1 = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")
  image2 = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(image1,None,10,10,7,21)
  image3 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  w, h, c = image3.shape
  binary_image = np.zeros((w, h), dtype= int)
  # extract one pixel from image
  pixel1 = image3[w//2][h//2]
  for i in range(w):
      for j in range(h):
         distance = distance(pixel1, image3[i][j])
         if distance > threshold:
             binary_image[i][j] = 1
         else:
             binary_image[i][j] = 0
```

I tried to do the following change, after I read the image

```
image4 = np.array(image3, dtype = 'float64')
```

If I change the type of the array the distance becomes extremely small (< 0.01) and the threshold value can't be applied.

How can I change my code in order to avoid overflow?

Comment: the overflow  is because you are taking 0-255 uint8 integer and **2. converting it to np.float is the right approach. The <0.01 does not make sense. Take 2 example pixels and calculate their dist manually and then follow the program steps.

Comment: @LiorCohen if the pixels are neighbours the distance is smaller than 0.1. For example if I have the values pixel1 =  [ 92. 137.  97.] and pixel2 = [ 91. 135.  98.] the distance would be 0.0060028747188588345

Comment: @Alex, for that example pixel1 = [ 92. 137. 97.] and pixel2 = [ 91. 135. 98.], what distance do you expect, and what distance does the code compute? I notice in `distance()` that the dh, ds, dv differences are divided by 179 and 255, and the final distance is divided by sqrt(3), so I'd expect colors that differ by a couple levels like your example would have distance of the order of 2/(179*sqrt(3)) = 0.006.